# Spring security annotations don't work on service layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring security to define access rules at method-level and facing with the issue is Spring security annotations are not working on service layer. But they work normal on controller layer.

Here are my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/api/register")
            .antMatchers("/api/activate")
            .antMatchers("/api/lostpassword")
            .antMatchers("/api/resetpassword");

}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MutableAclService mutableAclService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;

    public GlobalSecurityConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(mutableAclService));
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

}
```

}

Service does not work:

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public Iterable<Appliance> getAll() {
    return applianceRepo.findAll();
}
```

Controller works well:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Appliance>> getPage(@PageableDefault Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler pagedAssembler) {
    Page<Appliance> appliancePage = applianceService.getPage(pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(pagedAssembler.toResource(appliancePage, applianceAssembler));
}
```

Comment: you will need to add @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation in WebSecurityConfig or somewhere else.

Comment: @Zemzela I have added @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true) but is does not work.

Comment: please read this: http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-method-security-using-preauthorize-postauthorize-secured-el it should be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I'm wrong when putting `@PreAuthorize` on `getAll()` method but I was testing on `getPage(pageable)` method. Spring security configurations work well. Sorry for any inconveniences.